# How to prevent site to make unnecessary request using puppeteer to increase performance of our programs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, timeout, puppeteer, node-modules

**Using puppeteer how to prevent site to make unnecessary request so that site loading time decreased and program performance increase.**

==================================================================

```
 await page.on('request', (request) => {
        if (['image', 'stylesheet', 'font',].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
            console.log("###Aborting non essential request to speed up site...");
             request.abort();
        } else {
             request.continue();
        }
        });
```

**This above code will prevent from loading css and images but that did't give significant result**

**I also searched and find below code**

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', (request) => {
    const url = request.url();
    const filters = [
        'abc',
        'xyz'
       
    ];
    const shouldAbort = filters.some((urlPart) => url.includes(urlPart));
    if (shouldAbort) request.abort();
    else request.continue();
});
```

**As I don't know the site which I am scraping will request this others sites  .. so it above code is also not helpful for me.**

**Also tried puppeteer-extra and their plugins but still navigation taking time is too much.**

**So Ended with Uncaught error: Navigation timeout of xxxx ms exceeded**

Comment: I worked on this particular piece of code in my project as well. It works and reduces a lot of load-time loads. If you feel even this isn't giving the right result, consider running the puppeteer in headless mode. Hope that works!

Comment: In headless mode as well as using this also it reduces time but i want to the site which i am scraping don't request external resources and make further requests.

Comment: `await page.setRequestInterception(true);` intercept the request which is trying to further make calls to the (internal/external) scripts/images/URLs of the page you load. And with `request.abort();` you can skip loading. So technically it is doing the same what you are looking for. It is not requesting external resources. If you are looking to not load a specific URL you can also condition that in if-else the same way. You are already there, Good luck! :)